# Pass parameters from one jsp to another using post method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to pass parameters from one jsp to another.

I have tried using the post method, `<jsp:forward/>`, but it doesn't work.

I have created a `<form>` in html (parameters passed using `POST`), which is submitted to a servlet which processes the request and forwards it to another servlet that displays a page.

From this servlet i have created links to another jsp, passing through the parameters as `GET`s in the URL. However, I actually want to pass the parameters to another jsp using `POST`, and then pass it on to another jsp.

What solutions do you have or this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, the more work you put into your question, being thorough and showing the actual code you've tried that hasn't worked, the better answers you'll get. Also, when writing or editing a question, take note of the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the text area, and the **[?]** link above it. Very useful information there (like how I fixed the `<jsp:forward/>` thing for you -- it wasn't showing up in your question originally).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Request Dispatcher. You need to forward the request to the landing JSP.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are creating a multipage form that gathers information from the user across several distinct pages. In that case one option is to use hidden fields on a form to store the previous values. This of course means that as the pages progress the amount of data passing back and forth from client to server increases.

You may consider a server side approach by storing the interim values in a database for instance, then only passing a token back to the client. When the next JSP page is submitted, use the token to look up the values in the database.

Answer (score -1):

JSP has built-in **request** object.when one jsp redirect to another jsp with  some parameter, you can get parameter value using this **request** object.

```
       <%
String param1 = request.getParameter("parameter_name");

  %>
```

you can find example here -

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/RequestObjectInJSP.shtml

Comment: But this helps only when you pass parameters through a form, and not otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

> Why don't you call a page on the click of a submit button by creating
>   an url in the below format (in javascript):-  var
>   url="your_page_name.jsp?value1="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("your_text_field_or_any_other_field_id"));
>
> and then call the page by using your url
>
> document.your_form_name.action=url;

document.your_form_name.submit();

> and then use request.getParameter() method either in servlet
>   or in the jsp that u'v metioned in the url (servlet or the jsp u'll be
>   calling thorugh u'r jsp).

Comment: in this case the user can easily see it through right click and view source, whats the need of JSP than , its just simple java script.